# Pointerlock without fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, html, pointerlock

How is it possible, to use pointerlock without fullscreen mode?

The tutorials on the web uses the fullscreen api too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock

Comment: Is there a link to the demo you are talking about?

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wbhsP/

Just call `requestPointerLock` on a user action. It doesn't require the element to be fullscreen.

Comment: It also worth to mention that it should also work with mozRequestPointerLock - afaik, it wasn't the case few versions ago, which required being in fullscreen mode.

Comment: **ps**
jsfiddle's iframe sandbox don't allow pointerLock: here is the same demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/wbhsP/13/show/light/